# Get join values Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

According documentation about joins:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

As example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

OK, I have my values into $users.  If I do, with blade:

```
{{ $users }}
```

I can see this result, in JSON format.  But, How can I get each single value, using Blade?  (Ex: contacts.phone, or orders.price, in this example)

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user }}
@endforeach
```

You can substitute `$user` with any variable you wish.

Docs: [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)